Databricks jobs submit fails with Error: invalid character 't' looking for beginning of object key string
I'm trying to run a Databricks notebook via PowerShell in Azure DevOps. All of the variables below are properly read. I'm trying to format the JSON in 2 ways since I'm not sure which syntax is correct. I'm getting similar errors even though the payload seems to look fine when being printed.
JSON format 1:
$jsonObject = @{
    run_name = "Triggered via PowerShell"
    existing_cluster_id = $CLUSTER_ID
    notebook_task = @{
        notebook_path = $NOTEBOOK_PATH
    }
}

$jsonPayload = $jsonObject | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
Write-Host $jsonPayload

try {
    $response = databricks jobs submit --json $jsonPayload
} catch {
    Write-Error "Failed to submit notebook run. Error: $_"
    exit 1
}

$jsonPayload returns:
{"run_name":"Triggered via PowerShell","notebook_task":{"notebook_path":"/tests/utilities/tests"},"existing_cluster_id":"xxx"}

Error message:
Error: invalid character 'r' looking for beginning of object key string
Format 2:
$jsonObject = @{
  tasks = @(
    @{
      existing_cluster_id = $CLUSTER_ID
      notebook_task = @{
        notebook_path = $NOTEBOOK_PATH
      }
    }
  )
}

$jsonPayload = $jsonObject | ConvertTo-Json -Compress -Depth 10

Write-Host "Submitting the following payload to Databricks:"
Write-Host $jsonPayload
echo $jsonPayload

try {
    $response = databricks jobs submit --json $jsonPayload
} catch {
    Write-Error "Failed to submit notebook run. Error: $_"
    exit 1

$jsonPayload returns:
{"tasks":[{"notebook_task":{"notebook_path":"/tests/utilities/tests"},"existing_cluster_id":"xxx"}]}

Error: invalid character 't' looking for beginning of object key string
Databricks CLI v0.221.0 How can I modify the JSON to work with databricks jobs submit?

Try with $response = databricks jobs submit --json "$jsonPayload" or $response = databricks jobs submit --json "'$jsonPayload'"

Unfortunately, it didn't work.

The sad reality in Windows PowerShell and in PowerShell (Core) 7 up to v7.2.x is that an extra, manual layer of \-escaping of embedded " characters is required in arguments passed to external programs. This is fixed in PowerShell 7 v7.3+, with selective exceptions on Windows.
See the linked duplicate for details.

In the simplest case: databricks jobs submit --json $jsonPayload.Replace('"', '\"')

@mklement0 It works. Thank you!
